# Connecting and reading modbus protocol

Tags: python, modbus

I'm completely new to Modbus so sorry if this question seems rudimentary or if i miss certain aspects. Basically i have a sensor which outputs data in modbus protocol i have purchased a [USB TO RS485 Connector](https://core-electronics.com.au/industrial-usb-to-rs485-converter.html?utm_source=google_shopping&gclid=CjwKCAjwh5qLBhALEiwAioods6OLqQ1x3c1HTysFfbhqM3KbhtxtVuqlAn1_i88XltdBJRXZhjHnERoCcGoQAvD_BwE) im connecting this to my computer and its coming up as COM7. From reading the sensor documentation it seems like i need to connect to the sensor with the following specifications:

1. Port = COM7 -> checked it through device manager
2. baudrate = 19200
3. party = none
4. stop bits = 1
5. bytesize = 8
6. method is rtu

I am trying to establish this connection by adding in the following commands:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModBusSerialClient

serial = ModBusSerialClient(method='rtu', port='COM7', baudrate='19200', parity='0')
serial.connect()
```

I couldn't figure out how to add the stop bits and byte size but this is running with no issues.

From there i need to send the following command to the sensor so that i can read the data: 02 04 00 76 00 02 90 22 to registers 30118 and 30119. I have read the pymodbus documentation and know that i can do this by using the writetoregisters method but how do i convert that hex data to modbus protocol?

Comment: Looks like "02 04 00 76 00 02 90 22" is the byte sequence that needs to be sent out via the serial port (when using pymodbus its simplest to let the library generate this for you). These bytes mean Slave=2, Command=Read Input Registers, Reg=118 (physical), Count=2. The [read_input_registers](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/library/pymodbus.client.html#pymodbus.client.common.ModbusClientMixin.read_input_registers) function takes those human readable values, sends the appropriate query and returns the registers requested.

Answer (score 3):

See [here](https://www.simplymodbus.ca/FC04.htm) for a more detailed description of Modbus function code 04 (read input registers).

You will find out that `02 04 00 76 00 02 90 22` translates to:

`02`: slave address decimal 2 (unit for pymodbus)

`04`: function code 04 (read input regs)

`0076`: start reading on register decimal 118+30001=30119

`0002`: read 2 registers

`9022`: checksum of `02 04 00 76 00 02`, check it yourself [here](https://www.tahapaksu.com/crc/); don't forget to select HEX instead of ASCII

But as Brits wrote in his comments, the whole idea of using pymodbus is that you can just add this line to your code:

```
 regs = serial.read_input_registers(0x76,2,unit=2)
```

And then you can show the contents of the result with:

```
print regs.registers
```

Depending on your device you might need to change `0x76` to `0x75` to start reading on register 30118.